# typeError: unsetopt() is not supported for this option

Tags: python, pycurl

```
class ContentCallback:
        def __init__(self):
                self.contents = ''

        def content_callback(self, buf):
                self.contents = self.contents + buf

def exploitdb_search(name):
    if len(name) != 0:

        query = str(name) + ' ' + 'site:https://www.exploit-db.com/'
        for data in search(query, num_results=1):
            if "https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits" in data:
                x = ContentCallback()
                c = pycurl.Curl()
                c.setopt(c.URL, '{}'.format(data))
                c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, x.content_callback(data))
                c.perform()
                c.close()
                print(t.content)
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: where do you define `t` that's used in `print(t.content)`?

Comment: my question is why it keeps giving me this error about unsetopt() while i'm using setopt and refuse to show data here c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, x.content_callback(data))

Comment: no it's x ,i didn't change it ,my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the `c.WRITEFUNCTION` option should be a function. You're passing the result of calling the function, which is `None` because `content_callback()` doesn't return anything. Setting the option to `None` is interpreted as trying to unset the option, which isn't allowed for this option.

You should take off the argument list to the function so that you pass a reference to the function.

```
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, x.content_callback)
```

Comment: another question please .why it gives me an error at c.perform too?

Comment: f.py:27: DeprecationWarning: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN will be required for '#' formats
  c.perform()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f.py", line 14, in content_callback
    self.contents = self.contents + buf
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f.py", line 43, in <module>
    exploitdb_search(emnt)
  File "f.py", line 27, in exploitdb_search
    c.perform()
pycurl.error: (23, 'Failed writing body (0 != 7323)')

Comment: The argument to `content_callback()` is a byte string. You're trying to concatenate it to a regular string. Initialize `self.contents = b''`

Comment: Here are other questions about it: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpycurl%5D+%22failed+writing+body%22

Comment: class ContentCallback:
        def __init__(self):
                self.contents = b''

        def content_callback(self, buf):
                self.contents = self.contents + buf

Comment: and this one like that 

        query = str(name) + ' ' + 'site:https://www.exploit-db.com/'
        for data in search(query, num_results=1):
            if "https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits" in data:
                x = ContentCallback()
                c = pycurl.Curl()
                c.setopt(c.URL, '{}'.format(data))
                c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, x.content_callback)
                c.perform()
                c.close()